# Taking screenshots of multiple open browser tabs using Python

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to create a python script to take screenshots of multiple open tabs? If anyone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to each window and take screenshot of each window. All window in one screenshot is not possible. Use window handle to switch to each window and capture screenshot of each window.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would switch to different tabs (x being the iterator). 0 Would be the first tab and then 1,2 so on.

`driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x])`